# Unable to resolve dependencies in SBT - Have I missed a fundamental piece of config somewhere?

Tags: sbt

I have installed sbt 0.13.8 on a new machine (running osx) via `brew install sbt`, and now I cannot for the life of me manage to successfully resolve any dependencies from any repositories other than the defaults.

To illustrate this, I have created a very simple project, with the file structure as follows:

```
example/
  build.properties
  build.sbt
```

The contents of `build.properties` is simply:

```
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

And the contents of `build.sbt` is:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    libraryDependencies += "com.twitter.common.zookeeper" % "server-set" % "1.0.83",
    resolvers += "Twitter Repository" at "http://maven.twttr.com"
  )
```

That version of the dependency definitely exists in that repository, at http://maven.twttr.com/com/twitter/common/zookeeper/server-set/1.0.83/, yet when I attempt to `compile` or `update` the project it fails, and running `last` has just left me scratching my head:

```
$ sbt
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/rb/Workspace/example/)
> update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/rb/Workspace/example/}root...
[info] Resolving com.twitter.common.zookeeper#server-set;1.0.83 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.twitter.common.zookeeper#server-set;1.0.83
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/rb/.ivy2/local/com.twitter.common.zookeeper/server-set/1.0.83/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.twitter.common.zookeeper/server-set/1.0.83/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/common/zookeeper/server-set/1.0.83/server-set-1.0.83.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.twitter.common.zookeeper#server-set;1.0.83: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.twitter.common.zookeeper:server-set:1.0.83 (/Users/rb/Workspace/exampl/build.sbt#L4)
[warn]        +- root:root_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
...
> last
[info] Updating {file:/Users/rb/Workspace/example/}root...
[debug] Other repositories:
[debug] Default repositories:
[debug] Using inline dependencies specified in Scala.
...
> inspect resolvers
[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Resolver] = List(Twitter Repository: http://maven.twttr.com)
[info] Description:
[info]  The user-defined additional resolvers for automatically managed dependencies.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/rb/Workspace/example/}root/*:resolvers
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/rb/Workspace/example/build.sbt:5
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:externalResolvers
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:resolvers
[info]  {.}/*:resolvers
[info]  */*:resolvers
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:resolvers
> show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )), FileRepository(local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)), URLRepository(typesafe-ivy-releases,Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)), public: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 28-May-2015 10:50:23
```

As you can see, when inspecting the resolvers the twitter repository is there, but when running `update` sbt isn't even trying to use it (and it doesn't appear at all in the rather empty list of repositories output by `last`).

I can't find any clue as to what I'm doing wrong in the docs or update notes. Have I missed a fundamental config file or parameter somewhere whilst initially installing sbt?

Edit: I have managed to work around this by appending to `fullResolvers` rather than `resolvers` as follows:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    libraryDependencies += "com.twitter.common.zookeeper" % "server-set" % "1.0.83",
    fullResolvers += "Twitter Repository" at "http://maven.twttr.com"
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me on OS X, without having to use `fullResolvers`.

I am not sure if this is related but your `build.properties` file should be under the *project* directory.

This is how your project structure should look like:

```
.
├── build.sbt
└── project
    └── build.properties
```